# mybatis <id> <result> tag differences in <resultMap>

Tags: mybatis

I have done a lot of research and no avail. In Mybatis documentation, it says

> id – an ID result; flagging results as ID will help improve overall performance
>
> result – a normal result injected into a field or JavaBean property

If they can both inject into a field, and id has performance improvement, so what stops me from only using id at all? Is this just semantic that I will map the primary key to id tag?

I have tried:

```
<resultMap id="teacherMap" type="me.funmap.model.Teacher" autoMapping="true">
    <result column="t_id" property="t_id"/>
    <collection property="students" javaType="List" ofType="me.funmap.model.Student" autoMapping="true">
        <result column="s_id" property="s_id"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

and

```
<resultMap id="teacherMap" type="me.funmap.model.Teacher" autoMapping="true">
    <id column="t_id" property="t_id"/>
    <collection property="students" javaType="List" ofType="me.funmap.model.Student" autoMapping="true">
        <id column="s_id" property="s_id"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

the statement

```
<select id="getAllTeacher" resultMap="teacherMap">
    SELECT teacher.t_id, t_name, s_id from teacher INNER JOIN student ON teacher.t_id = student.t_id
</select>
```

result of statement

```html
       t_id    t_name           s_id

|          1 | teacher      |      38 |
|          1 | teacher      |      39 |
|          1 | teacher      |      40 |
|          1 | teacher      |      41 |
|          1 | teacher      |      42 |
|          1 | teacher      |      43 |
```

I get the same result using either id or result, so what is the difference between `<result>` and `<id>` tag in resultMap?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get the same result using either `<id>` or `<result>` is: when you use `<collection>` inside `<resultMap>`, if you declare `<id>`(s), MyBatis will only use `<id>`(s) to group rows having the same `<id>`(s) value, if you don't declare any `<id>`, it will use all `<result>`s to group rows having the same `<result>`(s) value.

If the result is:

```
       t_id    t_name           s_id

|          1 | An      |      38 |
|          1 | An      |      39 |
|          1 | An      |      40 |
|          2 | An      |      41 |
|          2 | An      |      42 |
|          2 | An      |      43 |
```

When you declare the `<resultMap>` as

```
<resultMap id="teacherMap" type="me.funmap.model.Teacher" autoMapping="true">
    <id column="t_name" property="t_name"/>
    <result column="t_id" property="t_id"/>
    <collection property="students" javaType="List" ofType="me.funmap.model.Student" autoMapping="true">
        <result column="s_id" property="s_id"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

You get only one teacher who has six students.

But when you declare the `<resultMap>` as

```
<resultMap id="teacherMap" type="me.funmap.model.Teacher" autoMapping="true">
    <result column="t_name" property="t_name"/>
    <result column="t_id" property="t_id"/>
    <collection property="students" javaType="List" ofType="me.funmap.model.Student" autoMapping="true">
        <result column="s_id" property="s_id"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

You get two teacher, and both have three students.